# ::webkit-scrollbar styles not working on DOM elements

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with overflow: auto

```
.div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and when i try to set the styles for the scrollbar, it doesnt work:

```
.div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

i tryed targeting with class, id, even the tag, but nothing works.

when i don't target anything before ::-webkit-scrollbar styles, the browser scrollbar acquires the styles, but i want to style the div scrollbar

Comment: Seems to work here. http://jsfiddle.net/wou2gk83/ The first div has the styled scrollbar, the second is for reference.

Comment: Something super weird just happened, i thought it could be some styles overlapping or something like that so i added !important just to be sure and it worked, but when i removed the !important, the styles stayed there, i think it could be some problem with the reloading of the page

Comment: Ah, the infamous caching problem. Let's hope it stays solved!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use one of javascript plugin to display custom scroll bars. Not all browsers support that what you wrote in your question.

[custom scrollbars examples](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/top-7-custom-scrollbar-javascript-and-jquery-plugins/)

Comment: While this is a valid concern, it isn't what the OP's question was about.

Comment: great!, i'll give it a try